# C# - Linq cast generic list to custom class

Tags: c#, list, linq, casting

I have declared a custom collection class like this:

```
public class WipCommesse
{        
    private string FNumCommessa;
    private int FIdTipologia, FTotQtaLetta;

    public int IdTipologia
    {
        get { return FIdTipologia; }
        set { FIdTipologia = value; }
    }

    public string NumCommessa
    {
        get { return FNumCommessa; }
        set { FNumCommessa = value; }
    }

    public int TotQtaLetta
    {
        get { return FTotQtaLetta; }
        set { FTotQtaLetta = value; }
    }

}

public class WipCommesseList : List<WipCommesse>
{

}
```

In my code I use Linq to group another list and I want to cast to my custom type

```
   WipCommesseList wipGrouped = 
   (WipCommesseList)myList.GroupBy(x => new
                            {
                                x.IdTipologia,
                                x.NumCommessa
                            }).
                            Select(g => new WipCommesse()
                            {
                                IdTipologia = g.Key.IdTipologia,
                                NumCommessa = g.Key.NumCommessa,
                                TotQtaLetta = g.Sum(i => i.QtaLanciabile)
                            }).ToList();
```

The definition of the class is the same but when i call ToList() method it return as System.Collection.Generic.List and the cast failed.

What can I do to convert correctly  to my class ?

Answer (score 7):

The code should be changed as follows:

```
 WipCommesseList wipGrouped = 
   new WipCommesseList(myList.GroupBy(x => new
                            {
                                x.IdTipologia,
                                x.NumCommessa
                            }).
                            Select(g => new WipCommesse()
                            {
                                IdTipologia = g.Key.IdTipologia,
                                NumCommessa = g.Key.NumCommessa,
                                TotQtaLetta = g.Sum(i => i.QtaLanciabile)
                            }));
```

This assumes that you have the following constructors in WipCommesseList:

```
public class WipCommesseList : List<WipCommesse>
{
    public WipCommesseList() : base()
    {

    }

    public WipCommesseList(int capacity) : base(capacity)
    {

    }

    public WipCommesseList(IEnumerable<WipCommesse> collection) : base(collection)
    {

    }
}
```

This allows you to cast any enumerable types based on WipCommesse into a WipCommeseList by creating a new WipCommesseList object.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> …
> Select(g => new WipCommesse()
>   {
>           IdTipologia = g.Key.IdTipologia,
>           NumCommessa = g.Key.NumCommessa,
>           TotQtaLetta = g.Sum(i => i.QtaLanciabile)
>   }).ToList();
> ```

The result of this will be a `List<WipCommesse>`.

But you're casting to a `WipCommesseList`. While `WipCommesseList` is a `List<WipCommesse>` the reverse is not true. When the runtime type is the base class you cannot down-cast because the object is not of the derived type.

You could add an explicit conversion operator to `WipCommesseList` that takes a `List<WipCommesse>` to allow the conversion: you would be be responsible for creating the `WipCommesseList` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast an instance of `List<WipCommesse>` to `WipCommesseList`. The derived class could have more methods/properties, casting works only in the other direction, if you have an instance of `WipCommesseList` to `List<WipCommesse>`.

You have two solutions:

1. If the class `WipCommesseList` is just as you defined it in your question, then it does not do much and you could just use `List<WipCommesse>`, maybe alias it in your files with `using WipCommesseList = List<WipCommesse>`
2. If the `WipCommesseList` is more complex you could create an extension method with similar functionality to `ToList`

Code:

```
public static class WipCommesseListExtensions 
{
    public static WipCommesseList ToWipCommesseList(this IEnumerable<WipCommesse> source) 
    {
        var list = new WipCommesseList();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The third option is to add constructors so a new object can be created from an IEnumerable of WipCommesseList and that is what List<T> has in its constructor list. (See below)

Comment: @netniV Yup, that is a good option too, the extension method feels more LINQ like though, that is why I favor this approach